# HP G42 won't boot, halts on recovery session menu

Tags: 11.04, boot

I have a HP G42. It was working but would randomly halt or restart the X session while running ubuntu 11.04.

Finally, last night, it froze and was not able to boot anymore. It gets stuck in the ubuntu splash screen, an if I choose the recovery mode in grub, it sort of halts in the session selection menu.

I have already run a memtest and it passes without errors.

How to proceed to further debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues. In order to get the recovery console working (I had the same issue - recovery menu would come up, but would not react to keyboard input), I had to unplug all my usb devices and add `nohz=off acpi=off` to my boot line in grub for the recovery mode. These boot parameters might differ for your system. I certainly would give `acpi=off` a try. That seems to be an issue for many system.

Once I was successfully in recovery mode, I was able to fix my xserver by renaming the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.

My issue was that I had the proprietary driver from ati installed, but then I used jockey to install the Ubuntu version of the fglrx driver over that. That left my system in an unstable state. Finally, I was able to purge fglrx from my system and installing the open source radeon driver.

Comment: It was an issue with the kernel module for the wifi adapter driver.
Don't have the bug at hand, but it's fixed in oneiric so I'm closing the question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Perhas you should do a check for all proprietary graphics drivers and updates, and if you are using proprietary drivers, perhaps see if there are alternative drivers you could use.

did you do a wubi install or is ubuntu your only OS? if so, what partition is it installed on? if it is ext4, perhaps as a last resort try reinstalling on an ext3 or 2 partition...

Comment: the only propietary driver I'm using is the broadcom's. It works fine in 10.10, so it's a 11.04 specific bug. also: don't put wild guesses as answers but comments instead